# Very simple flashing 8-LED ring and button on Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: gpio, python, hardware, led

This is my first Raspberry Pi project that involves an LED ring with button control, and I have some very basic questions.

I am making a halloween costume with a Raspberry Pi and this [SparkFun Lumenati 8-Pack LED](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/14357). I don't really need it to be perfect, and am not too worried about dim LEDs, so my question is, can I power it directly from the Pi's 5v pin and ground? In a tutorial I found, they use a PCA9306 Level Translator Breakout, in [this configuration](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/r/600-600/assets/learn_tutorials/6/9/6/Lumenati_Pi_2_bb.png). Should I bite the bullet and buy the breakout?

Additionally, I want to use a portable phone charging pack to power the RPI. It is 5V so I feel like it should work. I would plug it directly into the USB so I don't think I would need a voltage regulator. Thoughts?

Lastly, I'd like to have a button connected to the RPI that cycles the LED ring between 3 modes: flashing blue, flashing green, and flashing red. Should I connect the button to certain GPIO ports?

Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: Please follow the rule, one question, don't mix multiple questions in one question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**LEDs power supply**

Assuming those LEDs are similar to adafruit's dotstar leds, the maximum current is 0.48A (8 leds * 60 mA). According to [this answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/51616/63359), you can use the +5V pin and ground to power your leds.

**About the level shifter**

The [APA102C datasheet](https://cdn-hop.adafruit.com/datasheets/APA102.pdf) says that the input high threshold (VIH) is 3.5V (0.7*VDD), and the GPIO from the PI are 3.3V. So without the level shifter, you're out of spec.

**Power bank**

Running that out of a power bank should work, given the battery pack is rated for at least 5V 2.5A.

**Button**

Any GPIO should do, but you can have a look [here](http://razzpisampler.oreilly.com/ch07.html).

**About the PI**

This is probably not the answer you're looking for, neither a good site for posting it, but an arduino (mini or nano) will probably be easier to program, and will consume less (so your battery pack will last longer).